# SQLite Date Formatted as a String/Text but has no leading zero - How can I get the date?

Tags: sqlite, date, formatting

I have imported a csv from an internal data source to a sqlite database.

I have zero to no control of how that internal data source formats their data for me to extract as.

My problem is that the date fields, specifically the month, does not have leading zeroes.

Making it a bit problematical to extract the date with same exact string positions.

Here is some example data:

```
1/15/2021
10/16/2018
3/17/2019
5/12/2020
```

The issue is that the position is not as strict as if each date had a leading zero. Since I have no control of how the data is sent to me, I can only control how I parse it.

I am new to SQLite, although I have used Oracle/SQL Server many years ago.

Any tips or suggestions?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is the format of the dates? Post sample data.

Comment: Is the day part always 2 digits?

Comment: It varies, that is the main problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need string functions to convert your dates to `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Use a `CASE` expression which checks all possible formats with the operator `LIKE`:

```
CASE 
  WHEN date LIKE '_/_/____' THEN SUBSTR(date, -4) || '-0' || SUBSTR(date, 1, 1) || '-0' || SUBSTR(date, 3, 1)
  WHEN date LIKE '_/__/____' THEN SUBSTR(date, -4) || '-0' || SUBSTR(date, 1, 1) || '-' || SUBSTR(date, 3, 2)
  WHEN date LIKE '__/_/____' THEN SUBSTR(date, -4) || '-' || SUBSTR(date, 1, 2) || '-0' || SUBSTR(date, 4, 1)
  ELSE SUBSTR(date, -4) || '-' || SUBSTR(date, 1, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR(date, 4, 2)
END
```

Or, with `printf()` function:

```
SUBSTR(date, -4) || '-' ||
printf('%02d', date + 0) || '-' ||
printf('%02d', SUBSTR(date, INSTR(date, '/') + 1) + 0)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6104f91ebc3f4c27de4671130140426c).